# Understanding redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are moving up from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.0 and had a discontinued Podcast module.

I wrote my own version (it's tested and working), but now I need to redirect the old podcast URL to the new one.

I tried putting this line in the `.htaccess`, but it doesn't work.  Why?

```
Redirect 301 http://oar2.org/index.php?option=com_podcast&view=feed&format=raw&Itemid=100 http://oar2.org/rss.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've got the correct *from URL* and *to URL* in your `Redirect` statement (`Redirect <from> <to>`), then something important that you've missed is that you can't match against the query string using the `Redirect` directive (query string is everything starting with the `?`). You need to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_podcast&view=feed&format=raw&Itemid=100$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /rss.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is great... it's got me 90% of the way there.  One thing that happens is that it makes the new URL:

http://oar2.org/rss.php?option=com_podcast&view=feed&format=raw&Itemid=100

How do I make it end up as just:  http://oar2.org/rss.php

PS:  Thanks LOADS for what you've given me so far!

-- John

Comment: @user1460275 Add a `?` to the end of `rss.php`.

Comment: @user1460275 you should check the green checkmark next to the answer so that your question is marked as resolved

Comment: @user1460275: the check, or tick mark is to the left of Jon's answer. Make sure you are signed in, and to the left of the answer material, under the post score, is a tick symbol. It is not green by default, but clicking it will make it turn green, so that Jon gets the credit for helping you. Since you have asked a new recent question, would you mind doing this now?

Comment: @user1460275: I see you have logged in since I made the above request. I have now downvoted your question, and will undownvote it once you've replied.